# how to use Push function that is not working in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, express

// Here push function is not working

```
    var durations = []
    files.forEach(doc => {

        getVideoDurationInSeconds(`uploads/skill1/${doc}`).then((duration) => {
            
            durations.push(duration)    // Here push fuction is not working 
        })
        
        
    });

    console.log(durations)
```

// Here Push function is working

```
    var durations = []
    files.forEach(doc => {

        getVideoDurationInSeconds(`uploads/skill1/${doc}`).then((duration) => {
            
        })
        
        durations.push(doc)    // Here push fuction is working 
        
    });

    console.log(durations)
```

I want to store the duration of videos in array, i am getting all the duration of videos but not able to push in array.
I am using nodejs and get-video-duration package

Comment: you can use await instead of .then with getVideoDurationInSeconds

Comment: var durations = []
files.forEach(async doc => {

    const duration = await getVideoDurationInSeconds(`uploads/skill1/${doc}`)
    
    durations.push(duration)    // Here push fuction is working 
    
});

console.log(durations)

Comment: @Waelsy123 thanks dear... you were right.... i simply put my that in .finally(){}... thanks